# CSS3 Animation isn't work on chrome

Tags: html, css

I have my CSS3 animation that work fine on Firefox, but do not show up on Chrome browser.
you can see the final result on [www.stamp4all.com](http://stamp4all.com) the animation is the Arrows rotating.

Here is the CSS code:

```
/* Some stylesheet reset */
#sidemenu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  line-height: 1;

}
/* The container */
#sidemenu > ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 133px;
  /* The list elements which contain the links */

}
#sidemenu > ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/* General link styling */
#sidemenu > ul li a {
  /* Layout */

  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 0.14em dotted #3a3a3a;
  border-bottom: 0.14em dotted #1b1b1b;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  /* Typography */

  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  /* Background & effects */

  background: #282828;   /*  !!! animated menue background !!!! */
}

#sidemenu > ul li > a {
    border-radius:10px;
}


/* The hover state of the menu/submenu links */
#sidemenu > ul li > a:hover,
#sidemenu > ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #52cef0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#70d5f1, #52cef0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#70d5f1, #52cef0);
  background: linear-gradient(#70d5f1, #52cef0);
  border-color: transparent;
}
/* The arrow indicating a submenu */
#sidemenu > ul .has-sub > a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 120px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  /* Creating the arrow using borders */

  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #d8d8d8;

    /* effect, rotate 720 the arrows */
  -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: transform 1.5s;
  transition: transform 1.5s;
}
/* The same arrow, but with a darker color, to create the shadow effect */
#sidemenu > ul .has-sub > a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 120px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  /* Creating the arrow using borders */

  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid #000;

    /* effect, rotate 720 the arrows */
  -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: transform 1.5s;
  transition: transform 1.5s;
}
/* Changing the color of the arrow on hover */
#sidemenu > ul li > a:hover::after,
#sidemenu > ul li:hover > a::after {
  border-right: 4px solid #ffffff;
  transform: rotate(720deg);
}
#sidemenu > ul li > a:hover::before,
#sidemenu > ul li:hover > a::before {
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: rotate(720deg);
}
/* THE SUBMENUS */
#sidemenu > ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: -9999px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  /* The fade effect, created using an opacity transition */

  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.3s, width 1s, transform 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: opacity  1.3s, width 1s, transform 0.7s;
  transition: opacity  1.3s, width 1s, transform 0.7s;

}
/* Showing the submenu when the user is hovering the parent link */
#sidemenu > ul li:hover > ul {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 110px;
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<div id="sidemenu">
<ul> 
    <li><a href="index.php?main=include/about_us.html" >אודות</a></li> 
    <li class='has-sub'><a href="index.php?main=products" >חותמת מלבנית</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php?main=products/rectangle/p20.html" >P20 - 14X38מ"מ</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?main=products/rectangle/p30.html" >P30 - 18X47מ"מ</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?main=products/rectangle/p40.html" >P40 - 23X59מ"מ</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?main=products/rectangle/p45.html" >P45 - 25X82מ"מ</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?main=products/rectangle/p50.html" >P50 - 30X69מ"מ</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?main=products/rectangle/p60.html" >P60 - 37X76מ"מ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href="#" >חותמת מרובעת</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >Q30 - 14X38mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Q43 - 18X47mm</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li class='has-sub'><a href="#" >חותמת עגולה</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >R12 - 14X38mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >R17 - 18X47mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >R24 - 18X47mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >R40 - 18X47mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >R50 - 18X47mm</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li class='has-sub'><a href="#" >חותמת תאריך</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >S120 - 14X38mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >S160 - 18X47mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >S360 - 18X47mm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >S660 - 18X47mm</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="index.php?main=contuct_us" >צור קשר</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

Why is it not rotating in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1.5s;
```

Comment: That CSS contains a lot of unrelated stuff now. Start with the simplest working code, and work your way up, and then tell us where you run into trouble. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld8t9/3/

Comment: your example rotate the <a> element. I want the css arrows(borders arroes) will rotate....  there no element for these arrows

Comment: Just play with it little bit more and success make it rotat with your help.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Clear your chrome cache memory and previous browsing details

I give one sample

```
-webkit-animation-name: myfirst;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
```

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

```
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s linear 2s infinite alternate; 
animation:myfirst 5s linear 2s infinite alternate;
```

[Css tutorial for animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: I have cleard my cach and clear all history, also tried your code but still not working...

Comment: look at the css animation tutorial. you will get it

Comment: this tutorial is for html element. I want css arrow(made by borders) will rotate....

Answer (score 0):

As Leo reply, I use this code in order to fix the rotate arrows also in chrome browser:

```
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1.5s;
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform 1.5s;
  -o-transition:-o-transform 1.5s;
  transition:transform 1.5s;
  display:inline-block;
```

Thanks for all answers.